# SPring Boot external Jar config injection

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot application which is referring to Framework jar( Framework jar are common library jar's which are required by all microservices )

In framework jar i have used @Value annotation to read the config.

```
@Value("${isxyzFeatureEnabled}")
private static String isFeatureEnabled;
```

This value is not getting set when the application starts. However if i move this class to Individual microservice then it works.

I need to keep this class in framework as it will be reused by many microservices.

Any suggestions how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is static.
Unfortunately, "Spring doesn't support @Value on static fields."

Try this solution:

```
@RestController
public class PropertyController {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    private static String NAME_STATIC;

    @Value("${name}")
    public void setNameStatic(String name){
        PropertyController.NAME_STATIC = name;
    }
}
```

More info about that: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field